# Wait in For Each Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am installing a bunch of files through the for each command in powershell, however the script doesnt wait until the execution is completed before moving onto the next file, how do i ensure that it waits for the completion of each file before moving onto a next one? Here is my code so far.

```
$files = Get-ChildTtem $PSScriptroot

foreach ($file in $files)
{
if($file.extension.ToUpper() -eq ".appxbundle")
{
Add-AppxPackage $file.fullname -InstallAllResources
}
}
```

Comment: Assign the `Add-AppxPackage` line to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `Start-Job` and `Wait-Job` cmdlet to complete this:

```
$files = Get-ChildTtem $PSScriptroot

foreach ($file in $files)
{
if($file.extension.ToUpper() -eq ".appxbundle")
{
    Start-Job -Name Job1 -ScriptBlock { Add-AppxPackage $file.fullname -InstallAllResources }
    Wait-Job -Name Job1
}
}
```